# Trying to install php-soap and getting the 'No package php-soap available.'

Tags: linux, centos, php

Tried this:

```
yum install php-soap
```

Says:

> No package php-soap available.

Then tried this:

```
yum --enablerepo=centosplus install php-soap
```

Still same sh!t. 
Tried this:

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

Still no luck. Guys, where's the repo that contains the needed package?

The server is at vps.net btw...

Comment: what varsion of centos is it?  Did you try yum search soap or yum search php-soap? what version of php are you using?

Comment: `yum repolist`? `ls /etc/yum.repos.d/`? `rpm -qa | grep php`?

Comment: Did you fix this yet? Same issue here, PHP 5.3.3 Centos 6

Answer (score 6):

firstly open /etc/yum.conf file.
Find exclude line and erase php* command, then, save the file.

Then, 'yum install php-soap' command should work.

http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-install-php-soap-extension-in-apache-linux-php-server-remove-t1756.html comment by Mehmet

Worked for me :)

Comment: you are my hero bro! thanks! after 2 hours...

Answer (score 1):

I think that remi repo is what you are looking for.

Remi Dependency on CentOS 6 and Red Hat (RHEL) 6

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
```

CentOS 6 and Red Hat (RHEL) 6

```
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

Remi Dependency on CentOS 5 and Red Hat (RHEL) 5

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

CentOS 5 and Red Hat (RHEL) 5

```
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm
```

Comment: after run this command `find -name soap.so` in root folder i see this is soap path `./usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so` i set this line  `extension='./usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so'` `/etc/php.ini` file and restart httpd services in cent os 6. but still it couldn't enable soap service. any idea?

Comment: remove dot at the begining "extension='/usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so'" after that check with php -m if the module is loaded

Answer (score 0):

I have it in epel and rpmforge repos on CentOS 5. Did you try with --enablerepo:

```
yum --enablerepo=epel install php-soap
```

Comment: Still says `No package php-soap available.` It's unbelieveable! But appreciate your answer btw.